# Running certbot on an ECS instance

Tags: certbot, amazon-ecs

I am trying to run certbot on an ECS instance which is running a docker image (docker.io/existdb/teipublisher). The image runs well and I have associated it with a custom subdomain [teipub.dh-dev.com](http://teipub.dh-dev.com) using an elastic IP.

Trying to install and run certbot so I can have an Https connection has proven to be surprisingly difficult.

running as root, I install nginx with:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras list | grep nginx
sudo amazon-linux-extras enable nginx1
sudo yum clean metadata
sudo yum -y install nginx
```

then, following [this from nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/) I create `/etc/nginx/conf.d/teipub.dh-dev.com.conf` with the content:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name teipub.dh-dev.com;
}
```

but now when running `sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` to reload the new configuration I get
[image]

Which makes sense to me because when I built the task definition to run my image on the ECS cluster I used a portMapping between the hostPorts 80 and 443 and the corresponding containerPorts, which means something is already listening on port 80 (as well as 443).

running `sudo systemctl status nginx`, `sudo systemctl status httpd` or `sudo systemctl status apache2` on a clean ECS EC2 instance that is running the docker image cannot find those services.  So nginx is not installed let alone running before I try to run it.

So my question is: isn't there already a webserver on the ECS instance?  What is it and can I install the certbot on it? Or else, what is listening on port 80?

Alternatively - is there a different way to use certbot on an ECS instance?

BTW, and I don't think this is relevant, my main domain (dh-dev.com and [www.dh-dev.com](http://www.dh-dev.com)) allows https connections, probably through a certificate supplied by my hosting provider.

===Update===

following @dave_thompson_085's comment, I now understand (see image below) that a process called `docker-proxy` is listening on ports 80 and 443.  Which is why I cannot use nginx to configure certbot on these ports.  Any ideas on how to progress most welcome...

[image]

Comment: You say "nginx is not installed" but you did `sudo yum install -y nginx` which installed it, although TTBOMK that alone shouldn't have started it. `httpd` and `apache2` are NOT the names of nginx; do `sudo systemctl status nginx` and you'll see it, and see if it is running.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  ``sudo systemctl status nginx`` on a clean ECS EC2 instance produces ``Unit nginx.service could not be found``. Edited question to reflect that.

Comment: nginx isn't installed on a clean instance, but it is installed after you do the four commands you listed under "I install nginx with" and before you try (explicitly) to run it; that's the time I thought you were talking about. Anyway, do `sudo ss -antp | grep -e :80 -e :443` or if you prefer `netstat` instead of `ss` to see what is in fact running on those ports.

Comment: Thanks! ran the ss command and indeed there is a process called ``docker-proxy`` listening on ports 80 and 443.  So the question remains, how can use certbot (or any other SSL enabling solution) with this setup?